# Limit to events created in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking, event-tracking

I was wondering if there was a limit to the number of events that can be created on one property of Google Analytics. I'm aware that there's the 500 hits per session limitation for hits(including events) to be tracked and that there's the limitation of 10 million per month, but is there an actual limitation in the number you can create? (ie. you can only create 20 goals)

Also, if one decides to purchase Premium, are there additional goals to be had or is 20 goals the universal cap for all of Google Analytics accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any limits on the number of different events you can create nor the total number of events that your site can trigger beyond the 500 per session limit.

Goals have to be created through the Analytics web interface.    Events are created on the fly any time your website uses them.   The philosophy for them appear to be more like how pages and referrers are handled: "we'll take whatever the webite has, and we'll using sampling if there is too much data".

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the different category/action/label you can use for events.

One limit you did not mention was the requests per second.

> **ga.js:**
>
> Each ga.js tracker object starts with 10 hits that are replenished at a rate of 1 hit per second. Applies only to event type hits.
>
> **analytics.js:**
>
> Each analytics.js tracker object starts with 20 hits that are replenished at a rate of 2 hit per second. Applies to All hits except for ecommerce (item or transaction).

Source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/limits-quotas